# How zookeepers select its master in freshly connected zookeeper cluster?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, master-slave

Just started to study zookeeper architecture and its communication with the hbase

I have some doubt in leader election of zookeeper cluster

As far as i learned zookeepers will select its master using transaction 
id but when we freshly connect the zookeeper cluster all zookeeper's 
transaction id will be zero now how it will select its leader.....

Can any one please explain in detail.....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is too broad, make it more specific

Comment: Ok just tell me this. How zookeeper elects its leader in the freshly connected zookeeper cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several metrics zookeeper will take into consideration while in an election, like `epoch`/`zxid`/`id`, which you can verify from the implementation of `FastLeaderElection.totalOrderPredicate`.

To answer your question, if all your zk nodes start at the same time in a freshly cluster, the one with the biggest id (which is specified by you in the file `myid`) will be elected as the leader.